# Matching and replacement with gsub

Tags: regex, r

I have the following string

```
words_1<-c("Vneck","V-neck","V neck")
```

I want to get all of them to get replaced with "V neck"

any suggestion?

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I appreciate the sentiment but a slightly longer/less snarky comment might have the effect of educating a new user, e.g.: "the expectation for users asking questions on Stack Overflow is that they've made an effort to solve their own problems before turning to SO; for example, the criteria for upvoting/downvoting include 'shows research effort'. Can you show us what you've tried and where you got stuck?"

Comment: @BenBolker. You are right of course. I will be more polite in the future.

Comment: you can install the [pro forma comments script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) to allow you to post stock comments like "Can you show us what you've tried and where you got stuck?" (or even edit them to your taste); this greatly reduces the frustration of telling new users the same thing over and over ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try `sub`

```
sub("(V).*(neck)", "\\1 \\2", words_1)
#[1] "V neck" "V neck" "V neck"
```

Or a general approach would be

```
sub("([A-Z]+)[^A-Za-z]*([a-z]+)", "\\1 \\2", words_1)
```

Comment: *minimal* solution is `sub("V.?neck","V neck",words_1)`

Comment: Thanks a lot..it worked perfectly